# How to fix XRDP Problems with Raspberry Pi and Windows 7

Tags: raspbian-stretch, windows, rdp, xrdp

I just updated my Raspbian to the latest distro and fixed a problem with sudo apt-get update not working. The issue I'm having now is that my Remote Desktop isn't working anymore, which happened after fixing the issue with `sudo apt-get update`. What I get now when is a black screen with only the mouse appearing. I've reinstalled xrdp and tightvncserver while removing the realvnc and vnc4server programs. How do I fix this without formatting my MicroSD card?

Comment: xrdp, tightvncserver & RealVNC are all VNC implementations and share the save underlying code. You can only run one - certainly RealVNC disables the other 2. I don't know if you can use xrdp in conjunction with tightvncserver, but you probably need to pick one.

Comment: I just removed tightvncserver and restarted xrdp, and rebooted my pi3 and still nothing when trying rdp.